# How to duplicate UDP packets to two or more sockets

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I'm attempting to have two daemons running on the same port and IP but one is a server and the other is a client. Is there a method using socket options that would allow each socket to have a copy of the packet and let the daemons filter out the messages based on the protocol? It looks like reuse address blocks the first configured port and reuse port might just balance the packet between the two daemons.

Otherwise, I guess create another daemons to read the socket and send the packets to the correct daemon.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the UDP packets you are receiving are multicast or broadcast packets, then you can set `SO_REUSEADDR` (and, for BSD-based OS's, `SO_REUSEPORT`) on the socket (using `setsockopt()`) before bind()-ing the socket, and then both sockets will receive a copy of each incoming UDP packet.  (If the UDP packets are regular old unicast packets, OTOH, then doing the above will result in each received packet being received by only one of the two UDP sockets, which isn't what you want).

Note, however:  You refer to the two daemons as being a "client" and a "server" -- the implication of those terms is that the two daemons are going to communicate with each other.  If that is the case, then the typical approach would be to have the server-daemon bind to a well-known port number, and the client-daemon could bind to any port number (e.g. it could pass 0 as the port-number to `bind()`, and let the OS choose an available port-number for it).  Then the client-daemon could start the conversation by sending one or more UDP packets to the server's well-known port number, and the server can find out which port the client is sending from (and therefore what port to send reply packets to) by examining the fifth argument of its `recvfrom()` call.  In this case there is no need for the two programs to bind to the same port, and therefore no need for packet-forwarding.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Too bad it is a unicast packets and the protocol requires to use specific ports. Looks like I'll be creating another process to dispatch the packets to the correct service.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct at the end, you will need to have a third part that binds to the port and forwards the packets to the correct daemon.

The other way to do it would be to use three ports and use a firewall to redirect from the front end port to the backend ports; but that is a lot more complicated and not portable. But in the end you could use QOS or something. There is a wide range of possible types of use case behind the word protocol.